# Reading ResourceBundle in WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring-mvc, initializer

Is it possible to read a resource bundle during web app initialization in the WebApplicationInitializer? I have a filter initialized in the WebApplicationInitializer and I want to read the init-params from a file.

I tried it this way but *unprotectedUrls* is null when I try to invoke `setInitParameter("unprotectedUrls", unprotectedUrls);`

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Value("unprotectedUrls") String unprotectedUrls;


@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

    System.out.println("Initializing My Web App...");
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(MyWebAppContext.class);

    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("MyServlet", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

    javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic charEncodingFilterReg = container.addFilter("CharacterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    charEncodingFilterReg.setAsyncSupported(true);
    charEncodingFilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
    charEncodingFilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    charEncodingFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic authenticationFilterReg = container.addFilter("AuthenticationFilter", AuthenticationFilter.class);
    authenticationFilterReg.setAsyncSupported(true);

    container.setInitParameter("unprotectedUrls", unprotectedUrls);
    System.out.println("unprotectedUrls: " + unprotectedUrls);

    System.out.println("Initializing completed...");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not?

```
public class MyConfigInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("my-file.properties");
        String initParamValue = bundle.getString("key");

        Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("myFilter", "some.filter.qualified.name");
        registration.setInitParameter("key", initParamValue);
    }
}
```

You don't have to use `ResourceBundle`. You can read the properties from pretty much anywhere.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with Spring stuff? Like @PropertySource("xxx.properties")?

Comment: @user233552 You can put a `@Value` annotation on some field in some bean, but you will have to retrieve it and copy the value into the `setInitParameter()` method.

Comment: In my code above you can see that I did this but the @Value annotated field is null, thus, I invoke setInitParameter(..) with a null value.

Comment: @user `@Value` only works with spring managed objects. The `MyConfigInitializer` instance is created by the servlet container and is not a spring managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(WebAppInitializer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties"))) {
            properties.load(input);
            String value = properties.getProperty("memcached.profile");
            servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", value);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```